# How to insert an Image in powerpoint table cell using Open XML C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I have a table in PowerPoint which I have created programmatically using Open XML library in C# asp.net. Now I have to insert an image in one of its column. How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to add ImagePart in TableCell object. But its not giving any AddNewPart method. I don't know what should I do? Please help.